# Group by not returning 0 value

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql

My table contains `pk_id`,`reviewer_id`,`rating`.
There are 4 type of rating.

```
1-very good.
2-good.
3-bad.
4-very bad.
```

I want to calculate how much rating given by each reviewer.
Means:
If Akee having id 200 has given 2 very good,4 good,3 bad and zero very bad rating to different code.

I want result

```
  count--- rate

   2---------1

   4---------2

   3---------3

   0---------4
```

My query is

```
SELECT COUNT(RATE),RATE
  FROM CODE_REVIEW WHERE CODE_REVIEWER_ID= 200
 GROUP BY RATE;
```

It is showing result

```
  count--- rate

   2---------1

   4---------2

   3---------3
```

I want to show the fourth row that is 4 rating zero.
How can it be done??

Comment: The `Rate` must be primary key of another table?

Comment: Do you have a table where the rates are defined?

Comment: Hint: If there is no RATE=4 in CODE_REVIEW table, how is mysql to know that it should return row (0, 4)?

Comment: no there is no mapping table for rate.Can it be done anyway in code behind logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Rate is not the primary key in another table then you need define your own list of rates so MySQL knows what the permutations of `rate` are:

```
SELECT  Rates.Rate,
        COUNT(Code_Review.Rate) AS CountOfRate
FROM    (   SELECT 1 AS Rate UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 AS Rate UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 AS Rate UNION ALL
            SELECT 4
        ) AS Rates
        LEFT JOIN Code_Review
            ON Code_Review.Rate = Rates.Rate
            AND CODE_REVIEWER_ID = 200
GROUP BY Rates.Rate
```

Comment: This will not work. `COUNT(*)` simply counts the existence of a row. Since `4` *exists* as a row in the first subselect, the count will always be >= 1 even if the user never voted 4. What you must do is have it count on one of the columns in the `LEFT JOIN`'ed table since `NULL`s aren't factored into the `COUNT()` total.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do not have a separate table where the rates are defined.

```
SElECT * from (
  SELECT distinct(m.rate), countrate from code_review m 
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(rate) as countrate,rate FROM code_review 
     WHERE code_reviewer_id=200 GROUP BY rate) t 
  ON m.rate=t.rate) a
```

Comment: Just FYI: DISTINCT is not a function, it's applied to the entire row. Enclosing the column next to DISTINCT in brackets doesn't change that fact.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should push to try to get it in column format as it is simple as:

```
SELECT
    SUM(rate = 1) AS 1,
    SUM(rate = 2) AS 2,
    SUM(rate = 3) AS 3,
    SUM(rate = 4) AS 4
FROM
    code_review
WHERE
    code_reviewer_id = 200
```

But if you really need a row format, you could do:

```
SELECT
    a.rate,
    COUNT(b.rate) AS cnt
FROM
    (
        SELECT 1 AS rate UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS rate UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS rate UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 AS rate
    ) a
LEFT JOIN
    code_review b ON a.rate = b.rate AND code_reviewer_id = 200
GROUP BY
    a.rate
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it somthing like this

```
SELECT
            rates.RATE
            , SUM(COUNT) COUNT
   FROM
           (
           SELECT 1 RATE, 0 COUNT UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 RATE, 0 COUNT UNION ALL
           SELECT 3 RATE, 0 COUNT UNION ALL
           SELECT 4 RATE, 0 COUNT
           ) Rates
       LEFT JOIN
           (
               SELECT
                         RATE
                       , COUNT(RATE) COUNT 
                   FROM
                       CODE_REVIEW 
                   WHERE
                       CODE_REVIEWER_ID= 200
                   GROUP BY RATE
           ) Ratings200
           ON Ratings200.RATE = Rates.RATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT coalesce(c.cnt, 0), r.rate
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS rate UNION ALL SELECT 2
        UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) AS r
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(RATE),RATE
          FROM CODE_REVIEW WHERE CODE_REVIEWER_ID= 200
         GROUP BY RATE) AS c
    ON r.rate = c.rate;
```

1. The first subquery creates a list of possible rates. You can avoid it if you have a table which defines all rates;
2. Second subquery is yours;
3. `LEFT JOIN` guarantees that all rates will be shown;
4. `coalesce()` is needed to convert `NULL` into 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Rate,
    totCount
FROM 
(
    Select
        Rate,
        count(Rate) as totCount
    from
        Code_Review 
    where 
        CODE_REVIEWER_ID  = 200  
    group by 
        Rate
    union
    select  4, 0  
    union
    select  3, 0  
    union
    select  2, 0  
    union
    select  1, 0 
) AS T 
group by  
    T.Rate
```